# ODBC Connection to Oracle in Datazen BI tool

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, business-intelligence, dashboard, bi-publisher

Does anyone have managed to connect to a Oracle database using a ODBC driver in Datazen BI tool?

I just trying to connect to my Oracle test environment from Datazen server to create few dataviews for dashboards. The counfusion is what should I give as DSN? Following is my DBQ.

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.4.xxx.xx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEVUATENV)))
```

DEVUATENV is my Oracle instance and I gave this as DSN as well. But connection test is failing.

[image]

Can anybody help me? Thank You.

Comment: NOTE: I solve this issue by using a TNS name configured in Oracle and use it in both DSN and DBQ places.

Now the issue is i'm getting following error when I created a Data View (Just a Select * from a table) in Datazen server usign the above connection.

 Failed to update data: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer as you may find this usefull. We have now figured out that this issue was caused by .net framwork 4.5 installed in Server machine. Installing .net 3.5 sorted out the issue.